# Angular 6 - Firebase - Routing not happening properly after successful login

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, angular6, angular2-routing

Had spend a lot of hours to fix my issue, but couldn't make it. Also, I've come across related threads from SO, but still I don't find the solution to resolve this.

**Issue**

after successful signup, I got email verification flag to **`true`**. but when I try to login back with same credentials, routing to 'home' page is not happening. I don't know how to make that post method.

so far what have is.!

**firebase-service.ts**

```
export class FireBaseAuthenticationService {
  userData: any;
  constructor(
    public afs: AngularFirestore,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public router: Router,
    public ngZone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userData = user;
        localStorage.setItem('customerInfo', JSON.stringify(this.userData));
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customerInfo'));
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem('customerInfo', null);
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('customerInfo'));
      }
    });
  }
  userLogin(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        });
        this.setCustomerInfo(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log('err', errorMessage);
      })
  }
}
```

**user-login.html**

```
<fieldset class="clearfix">
            <p><span class="fa fa-user"></span><input type="text" Placeholder="Username" required #userName ></p>
            <p><span class="fa fa-lock"></span><input type="password" Placeholder="Password" required #userPassword></p>
            <div id="submit-btn">

              <span class="spn-submit"><input type="submit" value="Sign In"  (click)="authenticate.userLogin(userName.value, userPassword.value)"></span>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
```

**expected:**

1. Once login successfully I want to go to the 'home' page.

but right now, login-page loading for seconds and remains the same page.

pls, let me know more information is required.

Pls don't mark it as duplicate, I've already digged SO to find the solution. but I'm failed.

thanks to all

Comment: this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/home'])); Can you try adding a /

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @MuhammadKamran  let me try and come back

Comment: Still No luck... don't know how to track the failure

Comment: are you using routing guards ????

Comment: @skdroid yes am using route guard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are redirecting through service, so use `do` operator or return the observable and redirect in the component.

**using do operator**

```
userLogin(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .do((result) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['home']);
        });
        this.setCustomerInfo(result.user);
      }).catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log('err', errorMessage);
      })
  }
```

I did a navigate inside .do() BECAUSE a successful login will ALWAYS navigate to the currently set redirect URL.

If it did not ALWAYS do this then `router.navigate` would be wrong. However, given that it ALWAYS does this then this approach ensures consistency.

**create a method in component and redirect from the component.**

```
// service code
 userLogin(email, password) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }
}


// component code
userLogin(email, password) {
  this.authService.userLogin(email, password).then((result) => {
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['home']);
    });
    this.setCustomerInfo(result.user);
  }).catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log('err', errorMessage);
  })
}
```

Comment: I tried handling redirection in the component code as you have suggested. Result is still the same. Redirect does not happen

Comment: figured it out. I was missing  a slash at the start of the path